# Spray tool in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Where can I find a spray tool in Photoshop ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean airbrush? Hit `b` for the brush mode and in the Application Bar there's an icon for airbrush mode.

Answer (score 0):

Search the web for photoshop brush presets also, there are plently of custom brushes available.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an equivalent to Microsoft Paint's spray tool, there isn't one.

However, you can download a spray paint *brush* from [deviantART's collection of spray paint brushes](http://browse.deviantart.com/resources/applications/?qh=&section=&q=spray+paint).

I trust you know how to load brushes.